# C# - Marking base class of custom Form makes Design View display HTML

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, forms, visual-studio-debugging

Alright so.  I have an app with several dialogs that have a handful of events that they all respond the same way to, and all have a few methods they provide to the Presenter.  These have all been pushed up into a:

```
 public abstract class BaseFormClass : Form
```

and all the other forms are:

```
 public class DerivedFormClass : BaseFormClass
```

I've got a model-view-presenter setup going, so the base class has a few protected EventHandler<EventArgs>, and for each one is a similarly named function which is assigned to be called for that event, and a setter exists that the presenter can assign it's own function to be used as the handler for the event.  (In other words:)

```
protected void OnFormBeginClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (formClosing == null)
        return;

    formClosing(sender, e);
}

public EventHandler OnFormClose
{
    set
    {
        formClosing = value;
    }
}

protected EventHander<EventArgs> formClosing;
```

Then the presenter uses the OnFormClose setter to set it's own handler function to handle any necessary cleanups or whatever's necessary.

Now that the backstory is out of the way, **the main question is**, why when I make the simple change of marking the parent Form as abstract does my design view of my child Forms go from the normal design view to just spitting out a mess of HTML (well, not a mess, a single line of what appears to be the entire HTML of the form...)?

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this before, but trying the same in Visual Studio 2010, I get the error `The designer must create an instance of type 'WinFormsTestApp.FormA' but it cannot because the type is declared as abstract.`

[image]

I suspect this means exactly what it says - in order to display your derived form, for some reason known only to itself, the designer needs to create an instance of the parent form, and obviously can't do that. Sorry, but you will probably have to redesign your hierarchy. The VS designers make a lot of assumptions about the inheritance patterns used for forms and controls, so if you stray from the standard patterns, these problems are quite common.

Comment: Ugh.  This is why I can't stand being tied to the VS world...  thanks for your help.  :)